# ASP.Net throw a error on login - A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, compiler-errors, runtime-error, membership

I have some pages (web forms) on my host which retrieve some info from my MSSQL server and work perfectly but my problem is my 'log in' page.
In my login page, when a user enter the username or password incorrectly, the form acts normal and give user a related message, but when the username and password is entered correctly, it throws the attached error.

I think it's something about 'membership' or something but i can't figure it out. Here's my 'web.config' file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
      <section name="JahanPay.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <applicationSettings>
    <JahanPay.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="JahanPay_com_jahanpay_Webservice2ControllerService"
          serializeAs="String">
        <value>http://jahanpay.com/webservice2/index?ws=1</value>
      </setting>
    </JahanPay.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=127.0.0.1;Initial Catalog=ASPNETDB;Integrated Security=False;User ID=something;Password=something;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;Packet Size=4096" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SqlProvider" >
        <providers>
            <clear/>
            <add name="SqlProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlRoleProvider"
              connectionStringName="ConnectionString" applicationName="/" />
        </providers>
    </roleManager>
    <authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="users/signin.aspx" timeout="30"></forms>
    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <membership>
      <providers>
        <clear/>
        <add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ConnectionString" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" requiresUniqueEmail="true" passwordFormat="Hashed" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" minRequiredPasswordLength="4" applicationName="/" />
      </providers>
    </membership>
    <profile>
      <properties>
        <clear/>
        <add name="username"/>
        <add name="userfamily"/>
        <add name="companyname"/>
        <add name="sex" type="boolean"/>
        <add name="mobile"/>
        <add name="birthday"  type="DateTime"/>
      </properties>
    </profile>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
  </system.web>
  <location path="userpanel">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior">
          <enableWebScript />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
        multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    <services>
      <service name="Service">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="ServiceAspNetAjaxBehavior"
            binding="webHttpBinding" contract="Service" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

[image: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred]

What should i do?

---

**Once again, and because i think it's important i mention that it happens only when a user try to login with correct username and password.**

Comment: is your connecting sql in another machine or on the same machine?

Comment: @Webruster It's on a shared host.all my form(website) and  SQL-Server on same machine.

Answer (score 0):

You sql server is unreachable. If you connect over network try to ping the server. If the sqlserver should be on your pc try to restart the sqlserver.

Comment: He said already:
i have some pages(web forms) on my host which retrieve some info from my MS-SQL server and work perfectly

Comment: thank you for your post, as i mentioned in my post, my website is on he "host" and also my other pages are retrieving data from SQL-Server and also if you enter a wrong username or pass, it tells you that you did it wrong. so i don't think so.

Answer (score 0):

As Knutur0 pointed out, the error message says it couldn't reach your SQL Server.

The most obvious reason is the missing instance name in your connection string. Per default SQL Server installs as a named instance.

Please try: `Data Source=127.0.0.1\SQLEXPRESS` where SQLEXPRESS is the instance name.

Comment: Initial Catalog=ASPNETDB that is the same as Data Source=127.0.0.1\ASPNETDB. But he's right you should check if you can connect with the given information. Open sql management studio and try  to sql connect to 127.0.0.1 with the user and pass that is in your web.config

Comment: i have some pages(web forms) on my host which retrieve some info from my MS-SQL server and work perfectly.

Comment: Are those other pages using the connection string as specified in your config file?

Comment: @MatthewEvans yes, exactly!